# django/taggit - unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-taggit

I'm using django-taggit (see [here](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit)). This is what I have:

forms.py

```
from taggit.forms import *

    class MyForm(forms.Form):
        title = forms.CharField()
        my_tags = TagField(max_length=800, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'myTags'}))
```

views.py

```
       if 'submit_button' in request.POST:
            form = MyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
               cd = form.cleaned_data 
               f_title = cd['title']
               f_my_tags = cd['my_tags']

               p = MyData.objects.create(title=f_title)   
               p.tags.add(f_my_tags)
               p.save()
```

mytemplate.html

```
{{ form.my_tags.errors }}
{{ form.my_tags }}
```

Not sure why I get `unhashable type: 'list'` when I use `p.tags.add(f_my_tags)` in my views.py. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either add tags individually:

```
map(p.tags.add, cd['my_tags'])
```

this is equivalent to:

```
for tag in cd['my_tags']:
    p.tags.add(tag)
```

or pass them as positional arguments to tags.add:

```
p.tags.add(*cd['my_tags'])
```

this being equivalent to:
    p.tags.add(cd['my_tags'][0], cd['my_tags][1]... )

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you much! I've ended up using the p.tags.add(*cd['my_tags']).