# Sending tags via HTTP Post to Django web api endpoint

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-taggit

I am trying to send tags to my web application, using Django Rest Framework and Django Taggit. I tried to adapt the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23056025/2961929), but no luck so far. Here is my try:
models.py:

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_tags_display(self):
        return self.tags.names()
```

serializers.py:

```
class ToolSerializer(TaggitSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = serializers.Field(source='get_tags_display')

    class Meta:
        model = Tool
        fields = ('tool_id', 'name', 'tags')
```

views.py:

```
class ToolList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Tool.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ToolSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if 'tags' in self.request.data:           
            self.objects.add(*self.request.data['tags'])
    return super(ToolList, self).perform_create(self, serializer)
```

using httpie:

```
http --form POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/tools/ name="Hammer" tags:='["new", "heavy"]'
```

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: "but no luck so far" care to expand a bit upon this in your question?

Comment: so far I either got error messages or the tags were not added to the tags list and [] was returned.